# Git push is not working me: "Can't push refs to remote. Try running 'Pull' first to integrate your changes"

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have made the last changes I needed to finish my program and to push it to the repository, but now when I do a git push it always appears me this error.

I have already tried with git pull and git pull --rebase origin master (there is only 1 branch in my repository: the master branch), but neither this or anything is working.

What do I have to do?

Thank you.

[git push error](https://ibb.co/WnpZsPQ)

[git push error 2](https://ibb.co/KLDH68z)

Comment: Try `git pull origin master` and then `git push -f origin master`

Comment: Tried it. Still saying me the same.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text from your second screenshot as actual text, not an image. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12320578)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66539753/12320578) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66707633/12320578) answer your question?

Comment: @Dev-vruper never do this it will delete all your changes and download old version